# CORS error if PUT has credentials 'include' and Content-Type at the same time

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I am using JavaScript `fetch()` with following options:

```js
window.fetch(path, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
```

but I get error:

```
Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

and my `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` has wildcard `*`.

### It works without Credentials

It works fine if I don't add `credentials: include` and turn OFF auth on API server.

### It works without Content-Type

It works fine if I don't add `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},` and keep auth ON on API server. It means it is sent with `text/plain;UTF-8` but content is still JSON.

---

### Headers

Headers from my API server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
```

http://localhost:3000 is where is my front-end app running on.

---

#### Hints

- If i get this error, devTools in Chrome are not able to show me response headers (Access-Control-Allow-Headers etc.) and request headers shows `Provisional headers are shown` with only `content-type: application/json` in it and in *General* there is not `method: PUT` (there is not method at all). So it looks like Chrome stopped it before firing.
- Server is on different domain (intern web) and is running on `http` with `SameSite: None` without `Secure` but I have disabled security `Cookies without SameSite must be secure` in Chrome to walkaround it in development mode.

Is there any relationship between `credentials`, `content-type` and `PUT`? Is it possible to send `PUT` with `credentials` and `application/json`? If it is not possible - how should I send data with PUT method? `FormData` which are allowed content-type for `cors` are not supported by `PUT`.

Comment: When your request isn't a "simple" one, a preflight is sent. the server must respond to the preflight accordingly. the preflight is an OPTIONS request, not a PUT request, and will show up separate from the PUT request.

Comment: @KevinB I see I've been fighting with OPTIONS for a long time but all _preflights_ are handled fine and they has `method: OPTIONS` in DevTools - so I can debug them. This one does not have any method in request which is outgoing from Chrome and happens only with `credentials`.

Comment: Your error suggests that your preflight doesn’t indicate that content type is allowed for the given endpoint. Nothing you do on the client will remedy that

Comment: @KevinB As you suggests I started to dig into the preflight response and I've tried to set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` instead of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` wildcard and it **works**. Didn't find anything about it on MDN and I am not sure if it is the right reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [MDN documentation for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers):

> The value `*` only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without HTTP cookies or HTTP authentication information). In requests with credentials, it is treated as the literal header name `*` without special semantics. Note that the Authorization header can't be wildcarded and always needs to be listed explicitly.

You need to specify the headers you want to allow explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` from wildcard `*` to explicit `Content-Type` did the trick for me.